# Copy all files and folders from a source folder to multiple folders with a specic name

Tags: powershell

I have a source folder(c:\test*) and I want that folder copied to all folders in the same location (c:\resultaat) but only to the folders in that location that contains the name demo_profit.

I think I'm almost there, but I'm missing a small part I think.

```
$destination = get-item -include demo_profit* -path C:\resultaat\* 
copy-item C:\test\* $destination -recurse -force
```

thanks for your help

Comment: I think you will need a loop, because there is more than one destination. Something like a second line of `$destination | foreach-object { copy-item c:\test\* $_ -recurse -force }`

Answer (score 0):

The -Directory parameter of Get-ChildItem requires AFAIK PSv5

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory -Path 'C:\resultaat\' | ForEach-Object{
  if (Test-Path (Join-Path $_.FullName 'demo_profit')){
    Copy-Item C:\test\* $_.FullName -recurse -force
  }
```

Comment: The `-Directory` switch was added in PowerShell v3.0.

Answer (score 0):

So it is not clear if you want to copy the files to a folder containing an item named demo_profit, or to folder with demo_profit in the name. The second is simple, so I'll start there:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\resultaat\* -Directory | 
    Where{$_.Name -match 'demo_profit'} | 
    ForEach{ Copy-Item C:\test\* -dest $_.FullName -recurse -force }
```

That finds any folder within c:\resultaat that has 'demo_profit' as part of its name, and copies the desired files/folders into that folder. Example: C:\resultaat\Folder1_demo_profit would have all the files from C:\temp copied into it.

If you are looking for things named demo_profit, and want to copy the files into the same folder as that item you need to use the PSParentPath property, and some wildcards.

```
Get-ChildItem c:\resultaat\*\*demo_profit*
```

This command would find a file or folder with a path such as 'C:\resultaat\Amazon\az_demo_profit'. Then to copy files into the folder containing that you would use the PSParentPath property as such:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\resultaat\*\*demo_profit* |
    Select -Expand PSParentPath -Unique
    ForEach{ Copy-Item C:\test\* -dest $_ -recurse -force }
```